# the index page dont work main domain

Tags: indexing, dns, cpanel

says: "hi all, 
I have some problem with my cpanel ! 
I have uploaded my index.html file on public_html directory. 
but when I enter  my url (this: http://ads1plus2.com ) in brower. it do not appear and says: "If you feel you have reached this page in error, please contact the web site owner......."

can any one help me ?

by the way  the .htaccess file is OK
because the only line is:
DirectoryIndex index.html

cheers,"

can any one help me ?

by the way  the .htaccess file is OK
because the only line is:
DirectoryIndex index.html

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

http://ads1plus2.com/ loads the index.html page at my end, perhaps your browser is cached?